# selecting between functions based on user input combination - python

Tags: python

I have a small fastapi application that can get 4 optional arguments from the user, and  based on the user's input run a matching function like so:

```
def do_function(origin, destination, departure, arrival):
    if departure is None and arrival is None:
        do_a(origin, destination)
    elif departure is not None and arrival is None:
        do_b(origin, destination, departure)
    elif departure is None and arrival is not None:
        do_c(origin, destination, arrival)
    elif departure is not None and arrival is not None:
        do_d(origin, departure, arrival)
    elif departure is not None and arrival is None:
        do_e(origin, departure)  

    # and so on...
```

What is the most pythonic way of executing this code without using long and tiering "if-elif"?

I've seen a similar question here: [most efficient way to selection specific function based on input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718021/most-efficient-way-to-selection-specific-function-based-on-input) , but it doesn't apply to my case where there are only 4 optional inputs and more than 4 function options.

Comment: You already have a duplicate in the cases shown. There are only 4 combinations. Aside from that, the question can't be answered in general; it depends on **why** there are separate functions `do_a`, `do_b` etc., and **why it matters** whether the values are `None`.

Answer (score 1):

## Use Structural Pattern Matching (3.10+)

This situation is a very good one to use Structural Pattern Matching.

```py
def do_function(origin, destination, departure, arrival):
    match (origin, destination, departure, arrival):
        case (origin, destination, None, None):
            print(origin, destination)
        case (origin, destination, departure, None):
            print(origin, destination, departure)
        case (origin, destination, None, arrival):
            print(origin, destination, arrival)
        case (origin, destination, departure, arrival):
            print(origin, departure, arrival)
```

Here is a [tutorial](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/) on structural pattern matching, and here is the [PEP 622](https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/).

Comment: it doesn't work for: origin = 'TLV',
destination = None,
departure = 'NYC',
arrival = None, it goes to the second case although it shouldn't

Answer (score -1):

Create a map `dict[tuple[bool, bool], function]`:

```
function_map = {
   (True, True)  : foo,
   (True, False)  : bar,
   ...
}
```

```
func_key = departure is None, arrival is None
function_map[func_key](origin, departure, arrival)
```

Comment: Not all functions accept only those 3 arguments and in this order.

Comment: yes, he'll have to change the functions or add the args in the map